# Which one is the right answer in this boolean expression?

Tags: boolean-algebra

```
(A+B)' (A'+B')' =(A'B')+(AB)= A'B'+AB (Ans)

 OR

(A+B)' (A'+B')' =(A'+B')(A+B)

                = A'A+ A'B+ AB'+ BB' 

                = 0+ A'B+ AB'+ 0

                = A'B+ AB'  (Ans)
```

I get two different answers. I think the procedures I used in both are right. So which one is the right solution or are both of them wrong? The solution to the expression in my lecture has been given as 0 which really doesn't add up.

Comment: It looks like you confused it with the method for doing transposed matrix of a product of matrices.

Answer (score 1):

$(A+B)'=(A'B')$ and $(A'+B')'=(AB)$. This fact does *not* affect the multiplication between these two terms. So you should start
$$
(A+B)'(A'+B')'=(A'B')(AB)
$$

Comment: Okay, I see why this expression ends up as 0 now.